# Pass body from Aura component to Lightning web component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I am facing one issue to pass body from aura component to lwc.

optionGroup.html

```
<template>
  <h1>Child LWC</h1>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

OptionGroupLWC.html

```
<template>
  <h1>Parent LWC</h1>
  <slot></slot>
  <c-option-group>
    <p>child slot</p>
  </c-option-group>
</template>
```

OptionGroupExample.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
  <c:optionGroupLWC>
    <p>Parent Slot</p>
  </c:optionGroupLWC>
</aura:component>
```

Output:

[image]

Issue is `<p>Parent Slot</p>` does not render from aura component to slot in lwc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/interop_aura_composition):

> If a Lightning web component contains a slot, you cannot nest it in an Aura component.

I am afraid there is also no alternative for passing in aura facets to lwc - so for that particular Web Component you will not be able to wrap it in an old aura component